# Создание дочернего процесса в Linux, без чтения завершения его кода

Tags: python, linux, процесс, обработка-сигналов

Скрипт на питоне слушает порт и обрабатывает входящий поток. В случае, если информация на сокет не поступала больше времени `N`, то генерится ошибка `socket.timeout`(для этого используется функция `sock.settimeout(N)`). Разрывы связи не частые, поэтому в обработчике запускается программа через `subprocess.Popen`, которая посылает информацию на другую машину, что связь прервалась.

Проблема в том, что скрипт обработки не должен ждать завершения дочерней программы (что в принципе и происходит), но он и не читает код возврата, порожденной программы. В результате зомби процессы заполоняют систему (*Linux*).

Решено было так - сигнал `SIGCHLD` просто игнорировался в главном процессе. Есть ли еще способы порождать / игнорировать / читать статус порожденной программы без использования сигналов и ожидания её завершения? Желательно запускать так, чтобы отпустить дочернюю программу в свободное плавание и забыть про неё. Язык написания дочерней программы не важен.

Comment: Уточните, вы все же хотите получать статус завершения или нет (запустил и забыл про этот процесс)?

Comment: @avp, очень хотелось бы, чтобы основная программа **вообще** не прерывала свой поток исполнения(без обработки сигнала, без чтения статуса). Если такой возможности нет, то приветствуется любое решение, в котором основная программа будет выполняться без ожидания дочерней, и без зомби процессов. Пока найдено решение только с сигналами, но они поток исполнения прерывают всё-таки.

Comment: 2 вложенных форка. Во втором (внутреннем) выполняется свободное плавание. 1-й (внешний) сразу возвращается. Основная программа ожидет 1-й форк (это практически сразу) и работает дальше. Не знаю, как это пишется на питоне, а на Си если интересно могу написать пример.

Comment: 1- В чём проблема с `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)`? (posix) 2- вы реально видите много зомби или только предполагаете? (subprocess автоматически собирает кода  завершившихся процессов, когда вы новый пытаетесь запустить)

Comment: @jfs с signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) проблем нет. Данный метод, наоборот, помогает избавиться от зомби. Интересны были другие решения и подходы. Сразу после завершения дочернего тот стал зомбаком и не исчезал(долго не исчезал). Запуска нового процесса не дожидались. Соответственно и вывод был сделан про остальные.

Comment: @jfs разобрались, ошибка была в коде. Пока была жива переменная с результатом работы Popen процесс был зомби.

Comment: Если signal() вызов работает и даже с просто subprocess.Popen кучу зомби не видели, то о чём вопрос? Существуют множество способов организации запуска процессов (помимо упомянутой пары, можно демона руками запустить—совершенно излишне в вашем случае, но можно—или [использовать self-pipe trick, чтобы статусы собрать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30281111/4279), если у вас есть event loop. Можно celery или другую системе с message broker использовать для надёжной доставки (опять таки это был бы перебор в вашем случае) итд.

Comment: Опубликуйте свой ответ про ссылку на Popen()—[это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs хотелось увидеть множество решений, которое вы и привели. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen()` позволяет решить проблему процессов зомби. Модуль `subprocess` перед запуском нового процесса собирает коды уже отработанных приложений, но сам процесс зомби будет существовать до тех пор, пока существует переменная, являющаяся результатом `subprocess.Popen()`.